# How can you compile multiple typescript files with shared dependencies into a single javascript file?

Tags: jquery, node.js, typescript, webstorm

I have just started learning typescript, and I'd love to be able to write my code across dozens of files, modules or classes. But, I'd like to have all that compiled into a single .js file. which can be embedded in the html. This would mean I would not have to embed individual .js files in the HTML everytime I create a new one. I am trying to figure out header files, but I can't find find any clear explanation (or code samples) of how that works.

This is a NodeJS project in Webstorm. I am also using JQuery and I'd love to have JQuery imported and compiled into the .js file instead of being retrieved separately from the CDN each time - assuming that would make the site run faster!

Comment: Using the CDN for the jQuery library should be faster than embedding it yourself.  The main benefit of using a popular CDN is that the user will probably already have the file cached on their machine, before they even visit your website.  This means they won't need to download the CDN file at all, so it will load instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile with the `--out` compiler flag. I have a demo up on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: Thanks I got it working. One question from your video. you compiled the code withe "amd" option from the commandline. But I need to make the change to webstorm permanently - so it can autocompile each time. I added the "amd" option in the typescript filewatchers settings but I get an error on the console that says: "error TS5007: Cannot resolve referenced file: 'amd'"

Comment: Also I don't see a .js file output for the jquery.d.ts

Comment: For ("error TS5007: Cannot resolve referenced file: 'amd') It needs to be "--module amd" not "amd"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! That did take the error out, but the file does not compile any more. I've posted another question for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341807/typescript-filewatcher-not-working-in-javascript